# How to switch from metacity to compiz permanently?

Tags: 11.04, compiz, metacity

I know that by typing a command: `compiz --replace`
into the terminal window you can switch back to compiz, but this only works till the next logout/reboot. I want to switch for good. 
In Natty Narwhal I can't see any options in Preferences/Appearance to do that.
There must be a configuration file somewhere, I guess?

Please, help!

I checked the value you give and it was already set to compiz. 
However, only after using 'replace' command I get the required functionality like workspace edge.

Answer (score 2):

You can run `gconf-editor`, then navigate to `/desktop/gnome/session/required_components` and change window-manager from `metacity` to `compiz`.

[image: Before]
**Before.**

[image: After]
**After.**

If that does not work, try using `compiz --replace` as the value. If that still does not work, then add compiz --replace to your startup applications.

Comment: Thanks to your ideas + some other resources on the net I found a stable solution. I installed compiz fusion-icon package using synaptic and added it to star-up programs.
Thanks!

Comment: @Adam: you can mark the question as solved by clicking the tick next to my answer.

Comment: With a new installation of Ubuntu 12.04, the gconf-editor/desktop/gnome  list doesn't include *session*.  (The next entry in list after *peripherals* is *sound*).

Comment: @jwpat7 the question is tagged 11.04. It does not have anything to do with 12.04. If you are using a stock installation of 12.04, you are already using Compiz (if your system supports 3D accelerated Unity).