# More detailed path in Ubuntu dock on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

Is it possible, where there is a orange circle, write a more detailed path to the open folder in Ubuntu 18.04?

[image: dock popup path]

Comment: It should be related with metacity. Check both these pages: https://askubuntu.com/questions/54866/no-close-button-in-gnome-3?rq=1
https://askubuntu.com/questions/62177/how-to-switch-from-metacity-to-compiz-permanently

Comment: @Candan i think D.Ktt is asking about the texts "Documents" & "rating" which he marked with solid Orange circles.

Comment: here maybe : https://extensions.gnome.org ?